# margin won't animate back to 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to animate a button's size while constraining its position. It animates to its small size perfectly.

But animating to its larger size doesn't work as the margin is immediately set to `0px` and as a result not animated.

Here is the example:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 
  quickPickSelection();
  
 });
 
 function quickPickSelection() {

  var sectionIcons = jQuery("#quickPicks ul.sectionIcons li a");
  
  sectionIcons.click(function(){
     
   var icon = jQuery(this).children("span.iconContainer");

   
   if (!icon.hasClass("small")){
   
    icon.stop(true).animate({margin: 20, width: 40, height: 40},200).addClass("small");
   
   } else {
    
    icon.stop(true).animate({margin: 0, width: 80, height: 80},2000).removeClass("small");
     
   }
   
   return false;
  });

 }
```

```css
#quickPicks {
 
 float: left;
 width: 930px;
}
.sectionIcons {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 810px;
 padding: 10px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.sectionIcons li {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 margin: 0 10px 0 0;
 width: 80px;
}
.sectionIcons li .iconContainer {
 border: solid 1px #d8eaf0;
 margin: auto;
 display:block;
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;

 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 
 background: rgb(255,255,255);
 background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(242,246,249,1) 60%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(60%,rgba(242,246,249,1)));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(242,246,249,1) 60%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(242,246,249,1) 60%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(242,246,249,1) 60%);
 background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(242,246,249,1) 60%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#f2f6f9',GradientType=0 );
}
.sectionIcons li .iconLabel {
 display: block;
 text-align: center; 
 padding-top: 3px;
}

.sectionIcons li .iconContainer .icon {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display:block;
 
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 #fff;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 #fff;
 box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="quickPicks">
  <ul class="sectionIcons">
   <li><a href="#"><span class="iconContainer"><span class="icon"></span></span><span class="iconLabel">Tile 1</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><span class="iconContainer"><span class="icon"></span></span><span class="iconLabel">Tile 2</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><span class="iconContainer" style="margin: 0px; width: 80px; height: 80px;"><span class="icon"></span></span><span class="iconLabel">Tile 3</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><span class="iconContainer" style="margin: 0px; width: 80px; height: 80px;"><span class="icon"></span></span><span class="iconLabel">Tile 4</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><span class="iconContainer"><span class="icon"></span></span><span class="iconLabel">Tile 5</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><span class="iconContainer"><span class="icon"></span></span><span class="iconLabel">Tile 6</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><span class="iconContainer"><span class="icon"></span></span><span class="iconLabel">Tile 7</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><span class="iconContainer"><span class="icon"></span></span><span class="iconLabel">Tile 8</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><span class="iconContainer"><span class="icon"></span></span><span class="iconLabel">Tile 9</span></a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Click a tile and it shrinks in a constrained manner.
Click it again and it snaps to the top left because the margin has been set to 0 instead of animated to 0.

Comment: works here, using Opera. What browser do you use?

Comment: I found the 'shrinking' didn't work properly in Opera.

Comment: Please, don't sign your posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From **[Here:](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties)**

> Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. `margin`, `background`, `border`) are not supported. For example, if you want to retrieve the rendered margin, use: `$(elem).css('marginTop')` and `$(elem).css('marginRight')`, and so on.

`margin` cannot be animated properly, use a more specific type of margin, such as `marginTop`.

**[See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/9FPZb/1)**

Comment: Thanks, that's got it. I didn't realise it didn't support shorthand. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're removing the 'small' class as soon as the tile is clicked, thus setting the margin to 0 with CSS.
Try

```
icon.stop(true).animate({margin: 0, width: 80, height: 80},2000, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("small");
});
```

which will remove the class once the animation has finished.

You need to do the same with the initial animation too, as some browsers (Opera, for example) will stick the tile to the top as it shrinks.

Comment: That's not the problem here mate. You're right, but that's not what causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!

I've given that a go but no good: same problem :( Thanks again though.